# When is angle bracket required in initializing generic type in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, comparator

All three lines below compiled, are there any differences? If not, is it a good Java practice to always stick to the first one as it has the least amount of code?

```java
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap();
Map<String, String> k = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> l = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

And I don't understand why PriorityQueue without <> doesn't compile when I supplied the comparator lambda:

```java
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue(); // compiled
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue((x, y) -> (y - x)); // failed to compile
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((x, y) -> (y - x)); // compiled
```

Comment: `PriorityQueue` doesn't seem to have a constructor accepting only a `Comparator`. It does have a ctor accepting `initialCapacity` and a `Comparator` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Comment: @MattU [it does](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Comparator)) since java 8.

Comment: Well, is OP using 8? :D Good call though. I didn't even pay attention to the version of the docs I was looking at (not a Java dev).

Comment: @MattU I know you're joking, but they're using lambdas, so yes, they're definitely using at least java 8 :)

Comment: No. I was making a guess because I'm not a Java developer.

Comment: Don’t use minus as comparator. Minus can overflow. Since `Integer` has a natural order, you can simply pass `Comparator.reverseOrder()` to the constructor. Or `(x, y) -> y.compare(x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first form you give in the Map case uses raw types, and will result in compiler warnings.

```
$ cat D.java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
class D {
    Map<String,String> m = new HashMap();
}

$ javac D.java
Note: D.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

$ javac -Xlint:unchecked D.java
D.java:4: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
    Map<String,String> m = new HashMap();
                           ^
  required: Map<String,String>
  found:    HashMap
1 warning
```

So, you don't want to do that. That you can say it at all is just a leftover from Java before generics were added.

These two forms are equivalent:

```
Map<String, String> k = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> l = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

The `<>` syntax in the first of those two lines was introduced to avoid the repetition in the second; that is preferred syntax these days.

The `<>` operator infers the required types from context; what is needed is a Map from String to String, so that's what you get.  (That's an informal description, the exact rules are in the language specification).

Answer (score 0):

It is totally equivalent rows (see [diamond](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond)):

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((x, y) -> (y - x));
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>>((x, y) -> (y - x));
```

It is equivalent too (failed both):

```
new PriorityQueue((x, y) -> (y - x));
new PriorityQueue<Object>((x, y) -> (y - x));
```

They failed because of you cannot subtract Object type